# How to extract/display any two columns and their values from command output?

Tags: cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I need the TaskName and the Status columns displayed from `schtasks` command.

I tried the following:

```
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims= " %i in ('schtasks') DO echo %i
```

The output is not pretty looking. Current output if I run `schtasks` :

```
C:\Windows\system32>schtasks
Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc
TaskName                               Next Run Time          Status
NotificationTask                         N/A                    Ready
Folder: \Microsoft\XblGameSave
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
XblGameSaveTask                          N/A                    Ready
```

Sample desired output:

```
Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc
TaskName                                      Status
NotificationTask                               Ready
Folder: \Microsoft\XblGameSave
TaskName                                       Status
XblGameSaveTask                                Ready
```

Comment: What have you tried and what did you find difficult? Please read the [help] pages and take the [tour] to learn what sort of question can be asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it doesn't provide exactly the same output as your desired example, the following, seems usable, *(and better)*, to me:

```cmd
schtasks /query /fo list | findstr /r "^Folder: ^TaskName: ^Status: ^$"
```

Which should provide output like this:

```
Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc
TaskName:      \Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc\NotificationTask
Status:        Ready

Folder: \Microsoft\XblGameSave
TaskName:      \Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask
Status:        Ready
```

---

BTW, I'm unsure what version of Windows you're intending this for, but certainly from Windows Vista, through to Windows 10, this is the output format I'm used to seeing from `schtasks`:

```
Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
NotificationTask                         N/A                    Ready

Folder: \Microsoft\XblGameSave
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
XblGameSaveTask                          N/A                    Ready
```

Which means that your output, from your provided code, would look like this:

```
Folder:
TaskName
========================================
NotificationTask
Folder:
TaskName
========================================
XblGameSaveTask
```

That also means to get the output you desire, you'd need to omit the table header borders, as well as the second table column.

---

Given that, here's a rather OTT method of potentially achieving that from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "{=                                          "
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query ^
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[^=]"') Do (Set "}=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Set "}=!}:  =|!"
    For /F "Tokens=1,3 Delims=|" %%H In ("!}:| =||!") Do If "%%I" == "" (
        Echo %%H) Else Set "z=%%H%{%" & Echo=!z:~,41!%%I
    EndLocal)
Pause
```

This should output this for you:

```
Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\WwanSvc
TaskName                                 Status
NotificationTask                         Ready
Folder: \Microsoft\XblGameSave
TaskName                                 Status
XblGameSaveTask                          Ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with PowerShell.

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Select-Object -Property TaskPath,TaskName,State | Format-List *
```

If you are not able to run a PowerShell console, you can do it from cmd.exe.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ScheduledTask | Select-Object -Property TaskPath,TaskName,State | Format-List *"
```